# Django best practice for extending User model

Tags: django

I want to extend the build-in User model in Django.  I do this by just creating a subclass inherited from User.  The main problem is that when I retrieve user = request.user, this user is the built-in User type instead of the new subclass I create.
So I wonder what's the best practice to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

i think you forget to add `AUTH_USER_MODEL` in the settings.py details in docs [extending-the-existing-user-model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model), example:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'myapp.MyUser'
```

and by help in the comments, if you speak about best practice, better to use `AbstractUser` instead of `User`

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
```

Comment: Also, OP should extend AbstractUser, not User.

Comment: Don't forget to run `makemigrations` and then `migrate` after specifying `AUTH_USER_MODEL`

Comment: I extend my model from AbstractUser, but it report this error: 
              django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Auto-generated field 'user_ptr' in class 'CustomUser' for parent_link to base class 'User' clashes with declared field of the same name.

Comment: you need add your code and your full stack error in new question, and i'm sure someone help you.